# PHP Curl result giving trouble?

Tags: php, curl

I am working with NCBI Blast api. I created logic to get result in xml format but result is comming in html format and this result again going back to redirect to display xml format. when i check original url in browser it shows direct xml data. Can any one give me solutions. 
Visit this url you can find my problem [peerscientist.net](http://peerscientist.net). This is the code.

[image]

```
class BlastAPI{

    public function blastdata(){

        $url = "https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Put&QUERY=SSWWAHVEMGPPDPILGVTEAYKRDTNSKK&PROGRAM=blastp&FILTER=L&DATABASE=nr&FORMAT_TYPE=XML";
        $ncontent = $this->rid($url);
        echo '<br/>RID :'.$ncontent.'<br/>';
        $geturl = $this->geturl($ncontent);
        echo $geturl;
        $fulldata = $this->getfullData($geturl);
        if($fulldata != ''){
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($fulldata);
            echo '</pre>';
        }else{
            echo "Code Once";
        }
    }

    public function rid($url){

        $surl = $url;
        echo $surl;
        //header('Content-type: text/html');
        $content = file_get_contents($surl);    
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHtml($content);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

        $data = $doc->getElementById("rid");
        $rid = $data->getAttribute('value');

        return $rid;
    }
    public function geturl($rid){
        $srid = $rid;
        $mainurl = "https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Get&RID=$srid&FORMAT_TYPE=XML&DESCRIPTIONS=200&ALIGNMENTS=200&NOHEADER=true";
        return $mainurl;
    }
    public function getfullData($url){
        $murl = $url;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $murl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        $str = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if ($str === FALSE) {

            echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);

        }
        return $str;
    }
}
$nblast = new BlastAPI();
$nblast->blastdata();
```

Comment: i suspect you just get redirected to another page if your api call is wrong, hence the html. It does not look like your actually using an API, just faking a form submit, which they may not like

Comment: Ok..i get this api from ncbi website...thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: reading the perl sample you first run a put then poll for the results with a get request. https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=DeveloperInfo